# Curl to Javascript conversion with a -H

Tags: javascript, curl

I have this curl statement that I am using to talk to an API:

```
curl --basic -u 'para1:para2' -X POST https://Website/api/test -d '{ "info":"Test13" }' --header "Content-type: application/json" -H "TOKEN"
```

This curl statement works.

I am converting it into javascript for a chrome extension.

So far I have the code below:

```
  var url = "https://Website/api/test";
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', url, true, 'para1', 'para2');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');   
  var item_info = "Test13"
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify({"info":item_info}));
```

I am fairly certain that this is a proper conversion except for the -H "TOKEN" tag.

How would that tag convert to javascript? What is the name of that tag so that  I can look up more info on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-H` is the shorthand for `--header`, so it's just another header.

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('TOKEN', '');
```

Comment: I had tried to just add it to the other xhr.setRequestHeader before your answer, but adding this new line altogether was the answer. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, it's not chainable, and each call takes (key, value).